# How to write 10 million+ rows into csv file from vertica using python?

Tags: csv, pyodbc

How to write 10 million+ rows into csv file from vertica using python?
When I tried to write into bulk_data.csv as follows, it got struck after 200,000 rows.

```
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Vertica};SERVER=***;DATABASE=***;UID=****;PWD=***")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ***')
header = map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description)
with open('bulk_data.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('\t'.join(header) + '\n')
    csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n').writerows(cursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you don't write row by row for this amount of data. You use a `COPY` to process the file in bulk. If you're using Python, you may want to leverage one of the many Vertica specific projects which allow for batch import such as [PyVertica](https://pyvertica.readthedocs.org/en/v1.5.2/) from Spil Games.

Comment: does `COPY` support exporting data to a file?

Comment: @Ygg you would use `vsql` to export data to a file